# Why does R evaluate a subsetted NULL?

Tags: r, null, subset

AFAIK, any subsetting of NULL, such as `NULL[1]` in R will return NULL again. It seems though, that R still evaluates the part to use for subsetting:

```
system.time(NULL[1])
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
system.time(sample(1e7))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.582   0.010   0.598 
system.time(NULL[sample(1e7)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.575   0.011   0.594
```

I am using this in the context of creating a list within a function as in

```
l <- list(
    var1 = arg1[eval of complex calculation 1]
    var2 = arg2[eval of complex calculation 2]
    ...etc
    )
```

where any of the arguments (arg) to the function can be NULL.

It would save a lot of running time not evaluating the complex calculations, but I think I cannot circumvent the evaluation by testing for `if (is.null(arg))` within the list creation. Does lazy evaluation not apply here? Is there otherwise another solution to avoid evaluation?

Comment: why not, you can do `var1 = if (is.null(arg1)) NULL else arg1[eval of complex calculation 1]`

Comment: you can also redefine `[` :  `"[" <- function(a,...) if(is.null(a)) NULL else .Primitive("[")(a,...)` (this may screw up everything else  ... so if I would consider this, I would define it right before use and delete it right after use)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: you are right, I was trying to take a shortcut and leave out the NULL vars altogether using `if (!is.null(arg1)) var1 = arg1[eval of complex calculation 1]`, which resulted in an error. Still I find it curious why R makes the evaluation of the subset part at all.

Comment: `NULL[1/"a"]` returns an error, that's useful for many cases, I also believe your situation is quite rare (where subsetting NULL is a bottleneck) and chances are it could be dealt with upstream in a more elegant way